# Error importing outside bootstrap-sass library using webpack

Tags: webpack, bootstrap-sass, webpack-style-loader

I am in the process of creating a client-side application using React, Webpack and Bootstrap-Sass. I am trying to import an outside Bootstrap-sass library, but keep getting the following error in terminal:

```
 "File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/variables"
```

It appears as though the scss loader in my webpack.config.js is not properly reading the variables file in bootstrap-sass; however, I've tried using/creating several different scss loaders and none of them have been able to resolve this issue.

Here is my webpack.config.js file:

```
 var StaticSiteGeneratorPlugin = require('static-site-generator-    webpack-plugin');
 var data = require('./data');
 var path = require('path');


 module.exports = {
     entry: './entry.jsx',

output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path:  __dirname,
    libraryTarget: 'umd'
},

module: {
    loaders: [
{ test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader' },
{ test: /\.jsx$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader' },
{ test: /\.css$/, loaders: [ 'css' ] },
{ test: /bootstrap-sass\/assets\/javascripts\//, loader: 'imports?jQuery=jquery' },
{ test: /\.scss$/, loader: "css!sass?includePaths[]=" + 
    path.resolve(__dirname, "./bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/")},
{ test: /\.woff(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff" },
{ test: /\.woff2(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff" },
{ test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream" },
{ test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "file" },
{ test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml" }
    ]
},

   plugins: [
 new StaticSiteGeneratorPlugin('bundle.js', data.routes, data)
   ],
 }
```

base.scss file:

```
 // include bootstrap stylesheets
 $icon-font-path: "../node_modules/bootstrap-   sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/";  
 @import "../node_modules/bootstrap-   sass/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss";
 @import "../node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap-compass.scss";
 @import "../node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss";
 @import"index.scss";

 // include omni stylesheets
 @import "../bower_components/omni-bootstrap/assets/stylesheets/omni";
```

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

change the following line :

```
@import "../bower_components/omni-bootstrap/assets/stylesheets/omni";
```

to :

```
@import "../../bower_components/omni-bootstrap/assets/stylesheets/omni";
```